# Parse ISO8583 XML in android (using android studio)

Tags: android, xml, parsing, iso8583, jpos

I have this XML that i want to parse in android (android studio). Somebody please help. AM really stuck here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<message> 
<isomsg direction="response">
<field id="0" value="ew8wqq"/>
<field id="2" value="kdlaka"/>
<field id="3" value="3388382"/>
<field id="4" value="9302"/>
<field id="7" value="02061212223721"/>
<field id="11" value="9029221"/>
<field id="12" value="38383"/>
<field id="24" value="0920202"/>
<field id="32" value="Texted"/>
<field id="37" value="10031503992006830"/>
<field id="41" value="93039292"/>
<field id="49" value="uehee"/>
<field id="56" value="938339939393"/>
<field id="68" value="Test: 5001115750001"/>
<field id="102" value="5001115750001"/>
<field id="27" value="001"/>
<field id="39" value="00"/>
<field id="48" value="Successful"/>
<field id="54" value="38288928383"/>
<field id="58" value="73838383"/>
</isomsg> 
</message>
```

I will really appreciate. Thanks very much

Please find below the code that i use to get the response from the webservice

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "PostRequest");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("IncomingXMLMessage");

pi.setValue(GenerateXML());

request.addProperty(pi);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.100.10.10:9000/IWalletService.asmx");
SoapObject response = null;
httpTransportSE.debug=true;             

httpTransportSE.call("http://tempuri.org/PostRequest", envelope);

response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

int totalCount = response.getPropertyCount();
String resultString=httpTransportSE.responseDump;
Log.d("XML data ", resultString);

XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory
        .newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

String uResultString=resultString.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");

String uResultStringFinal=uResultString.replaceAll("&lt;","<");

parser.setInput(new StringReader(uResultStringFinal));
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to parse your xml data in Android you'll obviously need to use a parser for that. Google suggests the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) which I myself have found really useful. 
Google also provides some sample code for this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html). Explaining everything here would just be a duplicate to other answers to this exact same question. If Google's code isn't enough you might search for some other tutorials on the web!

Comment: I have looked at the explanations given and the samples and i cant seem to relate. I cant understand. Crosswind, please assist

Comment: am getting this XML from o web service and converting into a string.          response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                int totalCount = response.getPropertyCount();
                String resultString=httpTransportSE.responseDump;        so i have a problem posting this value into this method                                                                        private String readFields(XmlPullParser parser),......which only accepts parser. How do i convert this xml string into parser?

Comment: I honestly have no clue what you're doing there. You'd normally instantiate your parser and so on and then set an input to that parser which either takes a Reader or an InputStream. Maybe my example will help you - https://github.com/Crosswind/Vertretungsplan/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/gymnasium_beetzendorf/vertretungsplan/XMLParser.java
Where exactly are you getting the xml from? A downloaded file?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Am getting the response from a webservice. Am using kspoap2 to post the request and get the response. Now the problem is parsing the response and display to the user the necessary fields

Comment: Please edit your post with the code you use to get the XML because that would make things much easier, I believe.

Comment: dear Crosswind, i have edited the question and included the code i use to get XML from the webservice

Answer (score 0):

That's a JPOS response XML nested in `<message></message>`, not a SOAP XML,

see how JPOS does the parsing: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/iso/packager/XMLPackager.java#L117